# how to include FixVersion in Jira to vsts work item migration?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, jira, tfs-workitem, workitem

we have used Jira till now and want to migrate to VSTS. I found this link to migrate the workitems from Jira to Vsts.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/office/bulk-add-modify-work-items-excel?view=vsts
 However, in this migration,  excel it   does not have  some of the fields like FixVersion ? It just have Id, Title, WorkitemType, State,Reason, AssignedTo. How do I include other fields? Could any one please provide the documentation or resource links...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The work item fields in Jira and VSTS are different. For example the filed "`FixVersion`", it should be "`Integrated in Build`" in VSTS...

However you can create a query in VSTS, then click `Column options` to add the needed columns to display them in the query. Then open the query in Excel and copy the value of the field "`FixVersion`" to field "`Integrated in Build`". Do the same thing for other fields, then publish back to VSTS....

[image]